# Q is a 2x2 orthogonal matrix with complex elements, express those elements in terms of two complex variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

I want to express **Q** in terms of two complex variables $a$ and $b$, where **Q** is a $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix.

So far I have got the following:

Let $Q = \left[\begin{smallmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \\ q_3 & q_4 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$. Using $Q^T Q = I$ gives:

$$\begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_3 \\ q_2 & q_4 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} q_1 & q_2 \\ q_3 & q_4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} q_1^2 + q_3^2 & q_1q_2 + q_3q_4 \\ q_1q_2 + q_3q_4 & q_2^2 + q_4^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 &  0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

When I try and solve this, I get $q_2^2 = q_3^2$ and $q_1^2 = q_4^2$. However, I am not sure where to go from here. I haven't used the fact that they are complex numbers so far, so I might need to use that?

I've realised from the comments that this wasn't worded very clearly-- I am working on some practise problems, and this is how the question is phrased:

> "Assume that the orthogonal matrix **A** is $2\times 2$ with complex elements. Express the matrix elements of **A** in terms of two complex variables $a$ and $b$."

Hope that helps with clarity!

Comment: The question is unclear. What are you trying to achieve?  A general relation such that if someone gives you $a$ and $b$, you can construct an orthogonal matrix with them?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What are $a$ and $b$ and what do they have to do with the question?

Comment: Maybe you want to express $a=q_1 + i q_3$ and $b=q_2 + i q_4$? Then the condition that $Q$ is orthogonal means $|a|=|b|=1$ and $\Re(a \bar b)=0$.

Comment: @FShrike yes, that is what I am trying to do

Comment: @5xum I am looking for an $a$ and a $b$ that I can write $q_1$, $q_2$, $q_3$ and $q_4$ in terms of. So I know that $q_2^2 = q_3^2$, so I could for example write $q_2^2 = q_3^2 = a^2$, but I am not sure on whether I am taking the positive or the negative root for each of $q_2$ and $q_3$ (or how the fact that they are complex comes in to play).

Comment: Isn’t $SO(3,C)=SL_2C$? In which case you have a three complex dimensional object that you wish to parametrize with two dimensions worth of freedom.